# Calculated Column to DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

i have a calculated column using this code:

```
SalesMember_Cal_Column =
VAR ContextID = Table1[Id]
RETURN
    CONCATENATEX (
        CALCULATETABLE (
            DISTINCT ( Table1[salesmember] ),
            FILTER ( Table1, Table1[Id] = Id )
        ),
        Table1[salesmember],
        ","
    )
```

This works fine, but I would like to use it as a measure.

What can I change to use this as a measure?

Example:

I have data that looks like this:

```
Company CompnayID   SalesMember Role
Walmart   1            Ryan     Lead
Walmart   1           Vinnie    Lead2
Walmart   1             Danny   Lead3
Winco     2            Ryan     Lead
Winco     2           Vinnie    Lead2
Winco     2           Danny     Lead3
Fred Myer 3           Noelle    Lead
Kroger    4             Dennis  Lead
Albertsons 5            Nate    Lead
Safeway    6           Carol    Lead
```

I want to create a measure called SalesMember_Cal_Column that will give me this result:

```
Company CompnayID   SalesMember Role    SalesMember_Cal_Column
Walmart   1           Ryan      Lead    Ryan, Vinnie, Danny
Walmart   1           Vinnie    Lead2   Ryan, Vinnie, Danny
Walmart   1           Danny     Lead3   Ryan, Vinnie, Danny
Winco     2           Ryan      Lead    Ryan, Vinnie, Danny
Winco     2           Vinnie    Lead2   Ryan, Vinnie, Danny
Winco     2           Danny     Lead3   Ryan, Vinnie, Danny
Fred Myers 3          Noelle    Lead    Noelle
Kroger     4          Dennis    Lead    Dennis
Albertsons 5           Nate     Lead    Nate
Safeway    6          Carol     Lead    Carol
```

I want to make sure when I slice to a company then slice on sales member that only the associated sales member shows up in the new column.

For example, if I were to slice the above table to Walmart and sales member Ryan the result would look like this:

```
Company CompnayID   SalesMember Role    SalesMember_Cal_Column
Walmart     1          Ryan     Lead       Ryan
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be able to simply replace

```
VAR ContextID = Table1[Id]
```

with something like

```
VAR ContextID = SELECTEDVALUE ( Table1[Id] )
```

This will return the `Id` value from the filter context (or return blank if there are multiple).

Comment: is there a way to integrate unichar(10)? I am trying to make each name on a new line

Comment: Try `UNICHAR(10)` instead of `","` as the last argument.